Computation of Divergence is metpy 1.6
I think there's a potential issue with the computation that I wanted to raise, but first I needed to figure out exactly how this is computed to verify exactly what might be going wrong, and I think the simplest way would be to use the functions in the library which were used to compute it. If I can break up the computation into the library functions used to compute it, I should be able to then navigate through the pieces and figure it out from there.
The documentation just lists the equation $$\nabla \cdot U = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$ and as a non-software engineer, the source code is tad verbose to comb through. I recall seeing somewhere that it used to just be
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
div = mpcalc.divergence(u,v)
And div would have the same results as if I had instead done
div = mpcalc.first_derivative(u, axis = 1) + mpcalc.first_derivative(v, axis = 0)
For the data used, it was the sample data obtained from the import from metpy.cbook import example_data
and I was working with the example code used in the documentationHERE
Or I'd like to know the lines of code from the mpcalc library that would replicate the results, bc it no longer is just the sum of the 2 derivatives, something has clearly changed since I last used this package I think it was in 2019.
I made a couple plots (which I projected onto the globe using cartopy) to compare results:

Here's the code used to generate it
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import shapely.geometry as sgeom
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

import metpy.calc as mpcalc
from metpy.cbook import example_data

# load example data
ds = example_data()
u = ds.uwind;v = ds.vwind;
lon = ds.lon.values; lat = ds.lat.values
# Calculate the total deformation of the flow
div = mpcalc.divergence(ds.uwind, ds.vwind).values

div3 = mpcalc.first_derivative(u,axis = 1).values+mpcalc.first_derivative(v,axis = 0).values
error = (div3-div)/div*100
ax3 = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Orthographic(265-360,35))
shapename = 'admin_1_states_provinces_lakes'
states_shp = shpreader.natural_earth(resolution='110m',
                                         category='cultural', name=shapename)
cf = ax3.contourf(lon, lat, error,range(-100, 100, 10), cmap=plt.cm.bwr_r,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.colorbar(cf, pad=.15, aspect=50, label = '%error', orientation = 'vertical')

ax3.set_title('Error between Divergence and Computed Divergence')
ax3.add_feature(cfeature.STATES, edgecolor='black', linewidth=2)
ax3.coastlines()
gl = ax3.gridlines(crs = ccrs.PlateCarree(),draw_labels = True)
gl.xlocator = mticker.FixedLocator([270-360,265-360,260-360])
gl.ylocator = mticker.FixedLocator([30,32.5,35,37.5])

plt.show()

Additionally, the article linked here which references the document used to obtain the computation for the derivative has restricted access.

First, first_derivative uses a finite difference approach that is correct for non-uniform spacing (that is what is described in the Bowen 2005 article)
Second, divergence is indeed implemented as $$\nablab \cdot U = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$. However, as of MetPy 1.4, the partial derivatives are implemented to correctly account for effects of spherical/projected coordinate systems, which complicates the calculation and was previously implemented by the GEMPAK tool that MetPy has aimed to reproduce. See this PR for more extended discussion. These modified derivatives are implemented by the vector_derivative() calculation.

So the Cartesian partial derivatives do account for spherical coordinates, and they are accounted for using vector_derivative. Thank you! Also, the GEMPAK documentation might be what I was looking for. I don't know anything about tensor analysis or Taylor Series of a vector. This has given me some things to think about for what I should look into to learn about next. And yes, that was me on Github, thank you for responding to me there as well. I'll try to keep things in a single channel from now on, though there I was trying to keep it about just documentation

It's interesting how the results for divergence obtained using 1 methodology resulted in similar but in some places wildly different results in comparison to another (primitive calculus in spherical coordinates). It makes me wonder which methodology is actually closer to the real world values than the other methodologies. Do you know if this method is more commonplace in the field? I actually am a BA in meteorology who plans on pursuing a masters

Just FYI, GitHub is a great place to discuss questions and issues related to all of MetPy, including documentation. It also lends itself better to discussion than StackOverflow, which is better for direct questions and answers.

It is my understanding that GEMPAK, originally developed by NCEP, was implementing calculations as expected by most people.
